# Infinite scroll in Symfony using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, infinite-scroll

I wanted to show products from db using infinite scroll.

Here is my Controller:

```
    $start=0;
    $limit= 6;

    $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('classified')
        ->join('classified.statusId','status')
        ->andWhere('status.name=:status')
        ->setParameter('status','active')
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($limit)
        ->getQuery();

      $results = $query->getResult();

    if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

        $list = $this->renderView('search-result.html.twig', [
            'results' => $results
        ]);


    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData(array('classifiedList' => $list));
    return $response;
}
```

Ajax:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()>= $(document).height()){
                getmoredata();
            }

        })

        function getmoredata() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "{{ path('classified_list', {'type' : 'all'}) }}",
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                        $('.card-deck').append(response.classifiedList);
                        $('#spinner').hide();
                        console.log(response);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

So now what is happening is the first 6 results is repeatedly showing when the scrolling is triggered. I know this is not correct and I don't expect this to work properly. But what I don't know is what is the next step.
So do I need to add paginator or something?

Any help would be appreciated,Thanks!

Comment: The direction you seem to be going will only work when javascript is enabled. This would be very bad for search engines, as they generally don't have javascript, resulting in lower rankings. Have a look at http://infiniteajaxscroll.com for SEO friendly infinite scroll.

Comment: @JeroenFiege infiniteajaxscroll.com also requires javascript. Its a plugin for jQuery, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it uses progressive enhancement and falls back on server-side pagination without javadcript/ajax dependencies. Search engines will also use the server-side pagination for indexing.

Comment: @JeroenFiege Ya, so if i add pagination, this should solve isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track whether your ajax is requesting or not, so it will not do request multiple times when window reach the scroll limit. Also, you need to track the offset and whether you have more data to loads. e.g

```
 window.__isFetching = false;
 window.__offset = 0;
 window.__hasMoreData = true;

 $(window).scroll(function () {
    if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()>= $(document).height()){

      if(!window.__isFetching && window.__hasMoreData) {
         getmoredata();
      }
    }

 })

 function getmoredata() {
        window.__isFetching = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            // NOTE, you can pass current offset here in url
            url: "{{ path('classified_list', {'type' : 'all', }) }}"+"&offset="+window.__offset,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                    $('.card-deck').append(response.classifiedList);
                    $('#spinner').hide();
                    console.log(response);

                   // Note that here, server side response must have next offset and hasMoreData attribut.
                    window.__isFetching = false;
                    window.__hasMoreData = response.hasMoreData;
                    window.__offset = response.offset

            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
  }
```

in server side , which is symfony, you might want to do something like:

```
// Get offset from request query
$start= $request->query->get('offset');
$limit= 6;

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('classified')
    ->join('classified.statusId','status')
    ->andWhere('status.name=:status')
    ->setParameter('status','active')
    ->setFirstResult($start)
    ->setMaxResults($limit)
    ->getQuery();

  $results = $query->getResult();

if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){

    $list = $this->renderView('search-result.html.twig', [
        'results' => $results
    ]);


$response = new JsonResponse();
// And add offset and hasMoreData fields in response
$response->setData(array(
  'classifiedList' => $list,
   'offset' => $start += 1
   'hasMoreData' => count($list) < ($limit * &start)
  )
);
return $response;
```

Comment: no. added your lines to ajax, and then also i got the repeated results.

Comment: you have to do some improvements to server side code as well, please look for my edit.

Comment: still doesn't help. And when i printed the offset value on scroll, it always showing 1, meaning incrementing is not working.

Comment: `$start = $request->get('offset');` does this work? Am getting null for that!

Comment: do you mean `$start = $request->query->get('offset');` ? note the `query` property

Comment: ok , i have added `data: {offset : offset},` to js and its getting the value. Thank you for the help!